# Change error message generated by webform for duplicate email submission

Tags: webforms

I have a webform which takes a name and an email, the email field is set to not accept duplicates.

I have done this by choosing unique in the field settings (which is next to the required checkbox).

The error message it shows when a duplicate email is attempted is

'The value *email* has already been submitted once for the Email field. You may have already submitted this form, or you need to use a different value.'

How can I change this completely?

Answer (score 1):

There's other way if you don't want to code anything.

You can use [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)  Module

> This module allow override any translatable string on the site.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to fix this:**

1. You can do a **hook_form_alter** on the Webform.
2. Add your own custom validation function.
3. In the custom validation, add your validation on the Email field.

I haven't tried anything, but I think this would solve your problem and will override the messages for you.